# GRE Math subject test #61 Differential Equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone give me a hint on how to find the grams of salt leaving the tank?

A tank initially contains a salt solution of 3 grams of salt dissolved in $100$ liters of water. A salt solution containing 0.02 grams of salt per liter of water is being sprayed at a rate on 4 liters per minute in the tank. If the sprayed solution is instantaneously mixed and flows out at a rate of 4 liters per minute. How many grams of salt are in the tank after $100$ minutes?

I know that salt is being added at a rate of $0.08$ per minute but I do not know at what rate it is leaving the tank. My friend told me it is equal to $\frac {4x}  {100}$ where x is the number of grams salt present in the tank.

I have no idea where the $100$ came from? Are we not adding water and salt continuously such that the liters of water change? I know how to solve the question if I understand the rate at which salt is leaving.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I would think this is a differential equation you need to set-up, solve then evaluate at the appropriate time. There might be a short-cut, but I'm not sure right off.

Comment: Hold on a second, what does "0.2 grams salt per water" mean ? I am not familiar with this unit of "per water"

Comment: Yes, thank you. I fixed it.

Comment: The $100$ in $\frac{4x}{100}$ comes from the $100$ liters of water rather than the $100$ minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is solution being added to the tank at a rate of $4$ liters per minute, the tank is also being *drained* at a rate of $4$ liters per minute, so the volume stays constant at $100$ liters, throughout the process.